# Unable to show export-csv in PoweSshell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, export-csv

I have been researching the web to see what am I missing and can't find out, I run the command it goes thru the list of computers but the export doc is always empty.

Here is the code

```
    foreach ($computer in Get-Content "\\NETWORK PATH\user-computers.txt") {
    Write-host $computer
    $colDrives = Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer

    $Report = @()

    # Set our filename based on the execution time
    $filenamestring = "$computer-$(get-date -UFormat "%y-%b-%a-%H%M").csv"
    foreach ($objDrive in $colDrives) {
    # For each mapped drive – build a hash containing information
    $hash = @{
    ComputerName = $computer
    MappedLocation = $objDrive.ProviderName
    DriveLetter = $objDrive.DeviceId
    }
    # Add the hash to a new object
    $objDriveInfo = new-object PSObject -Property $hash
    # Store our new object within the report array
    $Report += $objDriveInfo
    }}
    # Export our report array to CSV and store as our dynamic file name
    $Report | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "\\NETWORK PATH\Drive-Maps.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I want to know what each computer currently got mapped network drives, thanks for all your help and guidance.

Comment: Define "empty" - is the file size (ie. `(Get-Item \\NETWORK PATH\Drive-Maps.csv).Length`) 0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're not getting output. I've rewritten your script for a few reasons I'd like to point out. First, your variable naming is not very clear. I'm guessing you come from a VBScripting background. Next, you're creating an array and then adding to it - this is simply not needed. You can capture the output of any loop/scriptblock/etc directly by assigning like tihs.

```
$Report = foreach($thing in $manythings){Do lots of stuff and everything in stdout will be captured}
```

If you write your script in a way that takes advantage of the pipeline, you can do even more.  Next, creating the object with `New-Object` is slow compared to using the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator introduced in V3. Finally, it seems you create a custom csv for each computer but in the end you just export everything to one file. I'm going to assume you are wanting to collect all this info and put in one CSV.

My recommendation for you to help troubleshoot, run this against your machines and confirm the output on the screen. Whatever you see on the screen should be captured in the report variable. (Except write-host, it's special and just goes to the console)

```
$computerList = "\\NETWORK PATH\user-computers.txt"

$reportFile = "\\NETWORK PATH\Drive-Maps.csv"

Get-Content $computerList | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host $_
    $mappedDrives = Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -ComputerName $_

    foreach ($drive in $mappedDrives)
    {
        # For each mapped drive – build a hash containing information
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $_
            MappedLocation = $drive.ProviderName
            DriveLetter = $drive.DeviceId
        }

    }
} -OutVariable Report
```

Once you know you have all the correct info, run this to export it.

```
$Report  | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $reportFile -NoTypeInformation
```